# VBA Excel copy cells range from another workbook to active workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy/transfer some cell values from one workbook, which is closed, to my currently active workbook.

```
  Sub FrontsheetAdd()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As String
  Dim Survey As Variant
  ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet") 'set to current worksheet name
  ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Site_survey_form.csv"
  Survey = ws2.Sheets("Ci_survey_form").Range("B17").Value
  ws.Range("D28").Value = Survey
  End Sub
```

but I am getting the error:

**Compile error: Invalid qualifier**

pointing at the following line:

```
 Survey = **ws2**.Sheets("Ci_survey_form").Range("B17").Value
```

There is a lot of similar problems, but they are mostly concentrated on copying a whole sheet from an external workbook or copying some cells from the active workbook to some external workbook. I need something in the reverse sequence.

How can I copy cell data from some external workbook to the workbook I am currently working on (active workbook)?

**UPDATE:**

After applying the code from the answer below:

```
 Sub FrontsheetAdd2()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, Survey, Survey2 As Variant

 Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet") 'set to current worksheet name
 Survey = CellValClosedWB(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Site_survey_form.csv", "City*", "B17")
 Survey2 = CellValClosedWB(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Site_survey_form.csv", "City*", "B15")

 ws.Range("D28").Value = Survey
 ws.Range("D30").Value = Survey2
 End Sub
```

I get the #REF value in my cells.

Moreover, the macro wants me to open the Excel workbook separately for every value.

[image]

[image]

Is there any option to fix it?

Comment: `ws2` is a string (holding the name of a CSV-file). A string has no sheets or ranges. You need to open the file before you can read from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is able to return a cell value, only after opening it, as already it has been recommended.

To extract a cell value from a closed workbook, you may be use an old way (kept for compatibility), `ExecuteExcel4Macro`. So, use the next function, copying the following code in a standard module:

```
Private Function CellValClosedWB(ByVal wbFullName As String, shName As String, cellsRange As String)
    Dim foldPath As String, fileName As String, cellAddress As String
    
    foldPath = left(wbFullName, InStrRev(wbFullName, "\"))
    fileName = Mid(wbFullName, InStrRev(wbFullName, "\") + 1)
        
    cellAddress = "'" & foldPath & "[" & fileName & "]" & shName & "'!" & _
                                        Range(cellsRange).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
    
    CellValClosedWB = ExecuteExcel4Macro(cellAddress)
End Function
```

It can be used (for your case) in the next way:

```
Sub testGetCellValue()
    MsgBox CellValClosedWB(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Site_survey_form.csv", "Ci_survey_form", "B17") 
End Sub
```

Or, in your adapted code as:

```
Sub FrontsheetAdd()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, Survey As Variant
  
  set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet") 'set to current worksheet name
  Survey = CellValClosedWB(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Site_survey_form.csv", "Ci_survey_form", "B17") 
  ws.Range("B17").value = Survey
End Sub
```

Comment: Object variable or with variable not set at 
ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet") 'set to current worksheet name

Comment: @MKR I took that line from your code, without doing any modification. An object must be set. Please, check the adapted code. Didn't the testing sub above this problematic one return the correct value?

Comment: I have the dialog window, which wants me to open the excel files. I would like to have the direct fetch the data

Comment: @MKR I do not understand what are you talking about... The above code is able to extract the value without opening the workbook. I did  not use any "dialog window" and it does not appear in your code, neither. Should I understand that **the above solution did not answer your question**? I cannot know how you try implementing it, so I cannot clarify an issue I am not able to understand...

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer hasn't solved my problem, but I am closer than I was before. I've updated my query. For sake of clarification, the Site-survey form CSV is the file from where I want to pick up data from. The target file is the City* file.xslm.   Is it possible to make the transfer such as this without population the dialog window as shown in the image?

Comment: @MKR The dialog in discussion only proves that the workbook **full file name** is wrong, or a sheet named "City*" does not exist.  Anyhow, the sheet name last character is **illegal for a sheet name**! The illegal characters are: \ / * [ ] : ?.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that it can be done in much simle way.

As per the tutorial under this link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9R0_h_aoSAE&ab_channel=ExcelCampus-Jon

We can simply do something like this:

```
  Sub Copyfromoneworkbooktoanother()



   Workbooks("City_survey_form.csv").Worksheets("City_survey_form").Range("B17").Copy _
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Frontsheet").Range("D28") 

   End Sub
```

In a situation, when our target cell is merged with others, we will get an error:

**Runtime error 1004 We can't do that for the merged cells**

In order to avoid this error, we should expand our target cells by merged range, like discussed here:

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/run-time-error-1004-we-cant-do-that-to-a-merged-cell.1146107/

so as a result our `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Frontsheet").Range("D28")` will be `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Frontsheet").Range("D28:F28")`